# PHP preg_match constant output

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I'm trying to parse out a string that could have multiple values and if one doesn't exist the array is outputting the part I'm looking for up one spot, causing me logic headaches.

What I'm trying to parse: `P1DT12H15M`, or `PT1H5M`, or `PT15M`
Basically it's P(Number of Days) T(Number of Hours)(Number of Minutes). The P and T are constant.  Here's the match string I have so far:

```
'/P([0-9]*?)D?T([1-2]?[0-9]?)H?([1-5]?[0-9]?)M?/'
```

It pulls everything apart, but the array output is not what I'm looking for.

```
PT2H gives Array ( [0] => PT2H [1] => [2] => 2 [3] => )
PT2H15M gives Array ( [0] => PT2H15M [1] => [2] => 2 [3] => 15 )
```

But

```
PT15M gives Array ( [0] => PT15M [1] => [2] => 15 [3] => )
```

I need that number to be in position 3, if possible.

Comment: What do you want to do with these values?

Comment: Why don't you use the PHP date objects? http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp = '/P(?:([0-9]+)D)*T(?:([1-2]?[0-9])H)*(?:([1-5]?[0-9])M)*/';

preg_match($exp, 'PT2H15M', $m); print_r($m);
preg_match($exp, 'PT15M', $m); print_r($m);
preg_match($exp, 'P1DT12H15M',$m); print_r($m);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => PT2H15M
    [1] => 
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 15
)
Array
(
    [0] => PT15M
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 15
)
Array
(
    [0] => P1DT12H15M
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 15
)
```

So, you can take `$P = m[1], $H= m[2], $M = m[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Your input strings looks like time interval specifiers. Let the PHP internal class [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) parse them then access the properties of [`DateInterval`] to get the values you need:

```
$int = new DateInterval('P1DT12H15M');
print_r($int);
```

produces:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 1
    [h] => 12
    [i] => 15
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] =>
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

You can access the properties directly (they are public):

```
printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes\n", $int->d, $int->h, $int->i);
```

If you need them as array you can even convert `$int` to an `array` and use them this way:

```
$date = (array)$int;
printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes\n", $date['d'], $date['h'], $date['i']);
```

If you insist, you can even emulate the behaviour of the `preg_match()` you struggle to create:

```
$string   = 'P1DT12H15M';
$interval = new DateInterval($string);
$array    = (array)$interval;
$matches  = array_merge(array($string), array_slice(array_values($array), 0, 6));

print_r($matches);
```

displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => P1DT12H15M
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 0
)
```

*(use `array_slice(..., 3, 6)` to keep only the time components)*